# How to fix broken login screen on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: unity, gnome, login, themes

I recently updated to Ubuntu 19.04 and I installed gnome tweaks to install themes.

Unfortunately I installed a login screen theme without backing up the original. Because of that theme my login screen is broken now.

Some images of login screen:

[image: Login Screen]

[image: Login settings]

[image: Intial icons]

I tried reinstalling gdm3 but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research on internet, I can say that gdm3 got broke because of my currently installed theme [Flat Remix] .
Simple way is to avoid gdm3 and use some other login screen like lightdm.
I just installed lightdm and everything is fine now.

Comment: `lightdm` has many advantages.